# What does this piece of code do in this OpenCV4Android sample application?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, android

Here is [the `ColorBlobDetectionActivity` class](https://github.com/nehiljain/opencv4android/blob/master/samples/color-blob-detection/src/org/opencv/samples/colorblobdetect/ColorBlobDetectionActivity.java) of the color blob detection sample, and the particular chunk of code that I am facing difficulty in understanding is Line#114 to Line # 135 in the `onTouch` method implemented in this class.

When the `onTouch` method is invoked, that is when the user touches a colored blob, the `int rows= mRgba.rows()` and `int cols = mRgba.cols()` is calculated. Since `mRgba` is a `Mat` which was returned by `onCameraFrame()`, it means it represents a camera frame.So I think `rows` and `cols` now represent the number of pixels along x-axis, and that along y-axis of the frame.

Since a frame is the area viewed by the camera (which in this app is the full screen of the device), so `rows` and `cols` represent the number of pixels along x-axis and y-axis of the screen respectively.

The next two statements are:

```
int xOffset = (mOpenCvCameraView.getWidth() - cols) / 2;
int yOffset = (mOpenCvCameraView.getHeight() - rows) / 2;
```

**The questions are:**

1. What exactly do `xOffset` and `yOffset` represent?
2. `mOpenCvCameraView` is an instance of `CameraBridgeViewBase`, which
   according to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.0.0/org/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase.html) is a basic class responsible for
   implementing the interaction of Camera and OpenCV. The
   [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.0.0/org/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase.ListItemAccessor.html#getHeight(java.lang.Object)) on `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` is silent, but
   I think it is also the width and height of the camera frame (in
   pixels?), so it should be same as `rows` and `cols`. Is that
   correct?
3. Can you explain a bit the formula they have used to calculate
   `xOffset` and `yOffset` (in the above two statemnets)?

Answer (score 1):

The delivered frames and the surface size are not necessarily the same. The maximum of the event.getX equals to the surface width.

I haven't seen the program running, but it seems like the offset determines the size of the touched rect. The rect is used for averaging the color, not simply displaying a single pixel's data.

Comment: When the camera view is fullscreen (see [Line#70](https://github.com/nehiljain/opencv4android/blob/master/samples/color-blob-detection/src/org/opencv/samples/colorblobdetect/ColorBlobDetectionActivity.java)), the delivered frame should be equal to the screen's dimensions, or I am not understanding the word "Frame" clearly, but according to the Definition # 5 [here](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/frame), "a frame is the image that is sent to the display image rendering devices."